# bindType vs delegateType in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i was just going through the Jquery doc's and basically came across the following peice of code :

```
jQuery.event.special.pushy = {
    bindType: "click",
    delegateType: "click"
};
```

the doc's has the following explanation for  `bindType` and `delegateType`,

> When defined, these string properties specify that a special event
>   should be handled like another event type until the event is
>   delivered. The bindType is used if the event is attached directly, and
>   the delegateType is used for delegated events. These types are
>   generally DOM event types, and should not be a special event
>   themselves.

now i don't understand the following :

The bindType is used if the event is attached directly, and
        the delegateType is used for delegated events.

what is `attached directly` and `delegated events` ??

Thank you .

Alex-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an example from [this brilliant article](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="http://domain1.com">Item #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/local/path/1">Item #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/local/path/2">Item #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://domain4.com">Item #4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS (direct bind)**

```
// Attach a directly bound event handler
$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

**JS (delegated bind)**

```
// Attach a delegated event handler
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.

Comment: Another reference, on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on